# Simple conversion of possibly-NULL value to flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a *simple* way to get `1` for a non-`NULL` column and `0` for a `NULL` column (e.g., in a `SELECT`), without adding a scalar function to do it?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Doesn't matter, I just want to detect `NULL` vs. not-`NULL`. But mostly this comes up for me with `INT` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three basic options:

1. `CASE WHEN`:

   ```
   CASE WHEN [TheColumn] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [MyFlag]
   ```

   or if you want it as a `BIT`:

   ```
   CAST(CASE WHEN [TheColumn] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS [MyFlag]
   ```

   Whether that's "simple" is a matter of opinion...
2. **If** you know non-`NULL` values will never be `0` (for an `INT` column) or `'FALSE'` (for a character column), you can shorten that a bit:

   ```
   CAST(COALESCE([TheColumn], 0) AS BIT) AS [MyFlag]
   ```

   ...but again note the assumption about `0`/`'FALSE'`.
3. On SQL Server 2012+, you can use `IIF` *(thank you, [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith))*:

   ```
   IIF(TheColumn IS NULL, 0, 1) AS [MyFlag]
   ```

Comment: I'm hoping someone has a better answer than this. :-) *(Why this is a community wiki answer: I do that when I'm answering my own question fairly quickly after asking it. While asking and answering is **perfectly valid** and actively encouraged on SO, I still prefer not to give the appearance of rep-mongering.)*

Comment: Your first option would be the most reasonable way to do this in SQL Server.

Comment: For 2012+ you can do `IIF(TheColumn IS NULL,0,1) AS [MyFlag]` which is basically the same but more concise.

Comment: @MartinSmith: !! That's an *answer*, man! I didn't know 2012+ had `IIF`! For me that's *by far* the clearest and most concise. (The project this came up on is using 2012, too! Sadly not all clients are, but great tool for the belt...)

Answer (score 2):

My first option would be the already posted answer by the OP, but an alternative is

```
select isnull(column * 0 + 1, 0)
```

Basically, if `column` is not `NULL`, then `column * 0 + 1` will be `1`, otherwise it will be `NULL`. I'm assuming `column` is an integer column, as suggested in the comments on the question, but it's usable for any type so long as you've got a function that converts that type to an integer (and returns `NULL` if and only if its input is).

It's similar in spirit to Jayvee's answer, but avoids any problems with any division by zero, and should be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: yes, this is probably the most elegant solution for an integer column.  By multiplying by 0 it makes clear that the column value is irrelevant as long as there is a value. Using ascii or len would work for any data type but it's a lot less readable than this one.

Comment: Great! As you say, very clear. Good pre-SQL Server 2012 approach for `INT` columns.

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
select isnull(ascii([TheColumn])/ascii([TheColumn]),0)
```

Comment: I had to go to the docs and mentally insert numbers to see how this works. This is not a good thing.

Comment: The limitation of this solution is the empty string, but it can be worked around with (len(x)+1) / (len(x) + 1).